# How to show the searched result again when the user comes back in ionic1

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created an application in which i have a list showing the contacts and a search bar when the user types any text in the search the list gets filtered according to it and it works as expected.But if the user selects the searched item and do some operations and come back to the same list the list should show the values(keywords which he typed in the search box) as well as the filtered result.But what actually happens is when i come back to the list page after doing some operations it shows all result instead of the filtered result.**Is there any possible way to show the filtered result even if we come back to the same page after performing some operations from the selected item from the list.**

```
<ion-content class="p-l-10 p-r-10 had-header kp-list" scroll="false">
<div>
  <div class="list nodata" ng-if="vm.farmers.length === 0">
    <h4><p>{{"nodatatoshow_message" | translate}}</p></h4>
  </div>

  <div class="list list-inset search_box m-t-10 m-r-10 m-l-10" ng-if="vm.farmers.length !== 0">
    <label class="item item-input search_cont"> <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="search..." ng-model="vm.search"> -->
    <input type="text" placeholder="search..." ng-model = "vm.search" ng-change="vm.getUsersByName(vm.search)">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<ion-scroll direction="y" style="height: 100%; margin-top: -5px">
  <!-- Option to handle no list -->
  <div>
    <ion-list class="trans-item ">
      <div class="FramerList list" ng-repeat="farmer in vm.farmers" ng-click='vm.gotoFarmerDetail(farmer)'>
        <a class="item item-avatar" href="#">
            <img src="main/assets/images/profile-pic.jpg">
            <h2>{{farmer.name | limit }}</h2>
            <h3>{{farmer.mobile_no}}</h3>
        </a>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-infinite-scroll 
      on-infinite="vm.loadMore()"
      ng-if="!vm.moreData"
      distance="10%">
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
  </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

Controller:

```
function activate () {
  Analytics.trackPage('Farmer-List-Page');
  vm.farmers = [];
  vm.totalcount = [];
  vm.moreData = false;
  DB.getContact('contacts', limit, offset, 'Farmer').then(function (result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
      $log.log('result of selected farmer', result);
      vm.farmers.push(result.rows.item(i));
    }
    $log.log('vm.farmers: ', vm.farmers);
  }, function (err) {
    $log.log('err', err);
  });

  Contact.get(['Farmer']).then(function (resp) {
    $log.log('resp...', resp);
    vm.totalcount = resp.length;
    $log.log('vm.farmers totalcount: ', vm.totalcount);
    $log.log('vm.farmers totalcount: ' + JSON.stringify(vm.totalcount));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you want unless you have disabled the [view caching](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/ionNavView/#caching) feature in any way.
You want it to be enabled. You might want to check the following things:

1. Check the routing code for your state, since it's possible to disable the view caching by adding `cache: false` property. You want to remove this property if it's set.
2. It's possible to disable view caching in the template by adding `cache-view="false"` attribute on your `ion-view` element. You want to remove this attribute if it's set.
3. Check your app config sections, it's possible to [disable view caching globally](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/ionNavView/#disable-cache-globally).